# Storing the googleapi Secret Keys in Firebase Environmental Variables

Tags: node.js, firebase, security, google-cloud-functions, secret-key

### Question

I would like to store a Secret API Key for googleapis in a secure location. When I store the Secret API Key from googleapis as a Firebase Environmental Variable, the `private_key` is not *processed* the same as when I `require("./privatekey.json");` See Issue below:

### Context

I have downloaded and decoded a Secret API Key from Google. Most [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#using-jwt-service-tokens) show saving the decoded JSON file within your project path and using `require` to pull the token into to code.

```
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = require("./privatekey.json");  <----- This is Bad!!


const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'email@serviceaccount.com';
const jwt = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE.private_key,
        null,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
```

I have used the `firebase-cli` to `firebase functions:config:set` Firebase Environmental Variables. When complete and redeployed, I run `firebase functions:config:get` and I see:

```
 "googleapi_credentials": {
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIE  ... q0DEg==\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n",
```

### Issue

When I configure `googleapis.auth.JWT()` I need to provide the googleapis Secret API Key. When I use `require` to pull in the Secret API Key, the requests work.

**However**, if I try to access the [Firebase Environmental Variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_environment_configuration_to_initialize_a_module) to provide the Secret API Key, the requests fail.

```
var jwt = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
        functions.config().googleapi_credentials.client_email,
        functions.config().googleapi_credentials.private_key, <----- NOPE!
        null,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
```

### Debug

To see what's different I compared the `console.log()` of the two tokens in the firebase functions log view. The token I stored in the JSON file and in Firebase Environmental Variables looks the same in code, that is, both strings match and they include many `\n` (line breaks).

Now, when I review what the `console.log()` returns in the **Firebase Functions Logs**, I see different tokens.

```
console.log("JSON Private.Key", privatekey.private_key)
```

The *view* in the logs returns a formatted string with all `\n` replaced by line breaks, and the token is accepted.

```
console.log("Private.Key", functions.config().googleapi_credentials.private_key)
```

**Logs returns a sting will all `\n` replaced by `\\n`.**, and the token is not accepted.

### Final Note

The `googleapis.auth.JWT()` function can take an object for it arguments? Do I need to take this into consideration if using Firebase Environmental Variables?

Comment: The example I've provided above isn't great because the googleapis documentation shows a better way to handle [local vs deployed Secret API Key management](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#service-to-service-authentication) for service to service auth. This might invalidate my question if this issue is due to the `googleapis.auth.JWT()` function's arguments.

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub around how add slashes is handled which might help answer some of your questions; https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/371

Comment: That looks like right, @sketchthat Do you want to grab the answer and I'll close this out?

Comment: Thanks Chadd - Just wrote one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase environment details have a problem with add slashes and can break `\n` strings.

There is an open ticket on GitHub which should be referred to; github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/371

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack I found posted by [YunjorGlez](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/371#issuecomment-337199010). This worked for me.

You can use **.replace(/\n/g, '\n')** to remove the extra `\` that is being added to the private_key.

```
const serviceAccount = functions.config().fireenv;

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert({
      "projectId": serviceAccount.project_id,
      "private_key": serviceAccount.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      "clientEmail": serviceAccount.client_email
   }),
   databaseURL: whatever,
   ...
});
```

Comment: Another option is to base64 encode the `fireenv` and then decode it on-read.